# Why is void pointer arithmetic allowed in gcc?

Tags: c, sizeof, void, pointer-arithmetic

The following code is compiling using gcc although `void ptr` arithmetic is not standard:

```
int main(){
 int a = 5;
 void* b = (void*) &a;
 b++;
}
```

Comment: Because the developers of GCC decided it was a good idea.  There are lots of other extensions provided by GCC.  Sometimes, you can get a notice from GCC when you (accidentally) use an extension, but you often have to request it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an extension supported by GCC.  It treats a `void *` like a `char *`.

From the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html):

> **6.24 Arithmetic on `void`- and Function-Pointers**
>
> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on
>   pointers to `void` and on pointers to functions. This is done by
>   treating the size of a `void` or of a function as 1.
>
> A consequence of this is that `sizeof` is also allowed on `void` and on
>   function types, and returns 1.

Comment: Technically, it is a non-standard variation of C, not an extension. In standard C, the compiler may define the behavior as an extension, but it must provide a warning (because the constraints in C 2018 6.5.6 3 are violated, and 5.1.1.3 1 requires a diagnostic). If you use `-pedantic`, GCC provides a warning, and then the behavior is an extension. (GCC is not a single C implementation; each variation produced by command-line switches is a separate variation, for purposes of interpreting the C standard.)

Answer (score -2):

This is explained by the fact that initially there was not the type `void` in C. Instead of it the type `char` played its role. And `sizeof( char )` is equal to 1.

For example I saw a very old legacy code where there was written

```
memset( ( char * )p, 0, n );
```

where the argument p has the type `int *`.

So it seems this was done for backward compatibility.

Comment: What does this explain? As long as there was a `char *` type, there was no need for arithmetic with `void *`. The code you show does not need arithmetic with `void *`. What code needs arithmetic with `void *` in order to be backward compatible with something? What something?